# grub minix* and usb* modules necessary?

Tags: grub-efi

Whats is the purpose of many minix*.mod inside /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ ?

And

Can i get less input lag deleting grub USB modules like ehci.mod, uhci.mod, ohci.mod, usb*.mod and disabling /boot/efi automounting inside /etc/fstab ?

keyboard/mouse input lag. I'am on Ubuntu 22.04 and while playing fps games on steam like cs_go i got a lot input lag. I still do not tested steam fps games with deleted mention modules, but I didn't lost USB capabilities even on grub ...
Thx

Comment: What input lag? Seems your question lacks details. Such as what version of Ubuntu are you using? Describe the lag.

Comment: @David keyboard/mouse input lag. I'am on Ubuntu 22.04 and while playing fps games on steam like cs_go i got a lot input lag. I still do not tested steam fps games with deleted mention modules, but i didnt lost USB capabilities even on grub ...

Comment: Moved the comment to the question where it belongs. So what you have is a steam issue not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @David It lags on Ubuntu too and i asked about possible overall improvement not an issue

Comment: Where are the details on that? Can only offer help based on what you put in the question. As for removing bits of Grub I would not do that but that is just me. Keep in mind Grub is a boot loader once running it is not going to cause any lag.